# Some parts of the text are not rendering in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-table

I'm facing another issue. Flutter web not rendering some parts of the text. Sometimes whole last words are missing.
Whole text is visible for few milliseconds then few parts of it get disappeared. I know the workaround which is to add spaces at the end of the text but it is painful.

Below is the code snippet which is showing the text.

```dart
  // ------------------ Data Cell of    N A M E
  DataCell(
      Container(
          width: 200,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                    Text(
                       product.name,
                       style: TextStyle(
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                     ),
                    Text("Volume: " + product.volume),
                   ],
                 ),
              ),
            ),
```

And btw I've printed the whole text value before `product.name` and  `product.volume` is printed complete value in console.
Below is the problem example

[image]

Comment: try using `Text("Volume: ${product.volume}")`

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I have not tried flutter web, I thought it may help using better concatenation, whether the problem is for string addition, then it may help

Comment: @ChristopherMoore but later the variable value is being deprecated

Answer (score 1):

We met this issue sometime in different places. For now we use this workaround (until it will be fixed):

```dart
Text(
  product.name + ' ' // add trailing space
)
```

Comment: Btw the way I knew it but it is a bit tedious. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to make `Text(text, wordSpacing: 0, ...)`